# how to store json object in array in javascript var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json

```
var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d); 

//here i am parsing json i have six rows in database (Microsoft SQL server 2008)
```

So my code is creating separate json object for each row so there is total six object in my variable  var objdata how to store objdata in array variable?

Comment: How do you send the response to the javascript code? Can't you just serialize the entire thing in one go and parse the array at once?

Comment: You need to show the data structure. Learn to use  [`console.log()`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201701030818251694827)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to map the object keys to an array.

```
var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d); 
var arr = Object.keys(objdata).map(function(k) { return objdata[k] });
```

Another approach would be to use the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method, wich wil return an array containing a `[key, value]` arrays for each property of the given object.

```
var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
var arr = Object.entries(objdata);
```

Or simply use the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method to get the object properties as an array. *(This may not work in some browsers)*

```
var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
var arr = Object.values(objdata);
```